# Why the player is floating in the air when using nav mesh agent component?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Without the nav mesh agent it's working fine but with it the ThirdPersonController is floating in the air. Then it's start moving automatic forward or backward.

Another problem i noticed with or without the nav mesh agent is that sometimes the character crouching/sitting/jumping hard on place for a second/millisecond when it's moving by keys or script it happen each some time.

I tried in the nav mesh agent in the inspector to change the height to 0 but i'm getting the value: 1e-05 The Base Offset value is 0.

I also have Animator and a Rigidbody components on this ThirdPersonController with the Nav Mesh Agent.

[image: Nav mesh agent]

Comment: The inspector showing `1e-05` isn't an issue. You realize that's equal to `0.00001` right?  It's basically a floating point error.  Happens all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should change inside the Nav Mesh Agent Compomenet the agent size. You should use it to build a collider around the player. Adjust the radius so that your player fits inside and adjust the height in such a way that it contains your whole player. If the collider is not centered, use the offset to centre it.